# Laravel route issue: "No query results for model"

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I'm pretty confused about how ROUTE works in these cases.

I have defined such a combination of routes:

```
Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController');
Route::get('users/{user}/tasks', 'UserController@tasks');
```

And everything is fine. No issue.
But

I did the same for the other Model:

```
Route::apiResource('tasks', 'TaskController');
Route::get('tasks/calendar', 'TaskController@calendar');
```

And for this combination I got the NotFoundHttpException :/

```
{
"message": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\Task] calendar",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException", ...
```

If I change in URI e.g 'task/calendar' then it works.
What I'm missing?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
Route::get('tasks/calendar', 'TaskController@calendar');
```

has to be moved above:

```
Route::apiResource('tasks', 'TaskController');
```

to work because the `apiResource` exposes the `tasks/{task}` route that matches before it reaches the `tasks/calendar` route.

The order doesn't cause an issue for Users route:

```
Route::get('users/{user}/tasks', 'UserController@tasks');
```

because it has a extra url segment(`/tasks`) that prevents it from clashing with `users/{user}`.

Checkout your current routes using `php artisan route:list`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `Route::resource` (or alternatively `Route::apiResource`), `GET` calls with the format `tasks/{task_id}/anything` or `tasks/anything` are getting routed to the `show()` controller method.

In my opinion, moving other `GET` routes above `Route::resource` smells hacky and is sloppy practice.

A more elegant solution is just to add another path to the route (such as `/list`), so that `show()` does not grab that route.

```php
Route::apiResource('tasks', 'TaskController');
Route::get('tasks/list/calendar', 'TaskController@calendar');
Route::get('tasks/list/tasks', 'TaskController@tasks');
```