# Can you help me with this ajax update notifications scenario

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-notification

I'm working with Laravel 9 to develop a forum project, and I have used **`database`** notifications for showing users new notifications such as *best answer* or etc.

The notifications list works correctly but shows the number of new notifications after the page refreshes. But I need to apply the ajax live update to get real-time applications user experience. So here is the `notification-header` part, which shows the number of new notifications:

```
<div class="header__notification-btn" data-dropdown-btn="notification">
    <i class="icon-Notification"></i>
    @if(count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications) != 0)
        <span id="unreads">{{ digits_persian(count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications)) }}</span>
    @endif
    <span style="display:none" id="elan"></span>
</div>
```

Then I tried applying the Ajax part like this:

```
        notifcount = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'new-notifications-exists',
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(notifcount == 0){
                            notifcount = response.notifcount;
                        }
                        if(response.notifcount > notifcount){
                            notifcount = response.notifcount;
                            new_notifications_found();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 2000);
        });
        function new_notifications_found(){
            $("#unreads").hide();
            $("#elan").show();
            $("#elan").html("+.");
        }
```

And this is the `new-notifications-exists` URI handler:

```
Route::get('/new-notifications-exists', 'ToolsController@count_notifz');
```

Controller Method:

```
public function count_notifz()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            $notiflist = DB::table('notifications')->where('notifiable_id',auth()->user()->id)->whereNull('read_at')->get();
            $notifcount = $notiflist->count();
            $response = array('notifcount' => $notifcount);
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```

So: When I get a new notification, the `<span style="display:none" id="elan"></span>` must be appeared because of the js function `new_question_found()` which eventually hide `#unreads` and show `#elan` div instead.

But this thing does not work, and I get this error at the Console:

[image]

### "No query results for model [App\Models\Question] new-notifications-exists"**

I don't know really what's going wrong here.

So if you have any idea about this or know how to apply ajax properly for these notifications, please let me know...

I would appreciate that.

Comment: Try to debug your backend code. i.e : you can do `dd` in your laravel code check what query is printing . Check what `$notiflist` has .

Comment: From your error message I think you have used Quetion model some where that may have some issues , check once if you have Quetion model in App\Models directory

Comment: There should be something wrong with your routes, look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68672766/laravel-route-issue-no-query-results-for-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change controller method to this:

```php
public function count_notifz()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            $notifcount = count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications);
            return response()->json(['notifcount' => $notifcount]);
        }
    }
```

It works in your header blade then should work everywhere else.

And please put a slash at the beginning of you ajax URL:

```
url: '/new-notifications-exists'
```

Also there is a problem with your ajax:

```js
if(notifcount == 0){
    notifcount = response.notifcount;
}
```

If you assign `response.notifcount` to `notifcount` then next `if` will never be true! therefore the  `new_notifications_found()` never executes.

**So just simply remove it**. The logic will be intact.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/new-notifications-exists',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.notifcount > notifcount){
            notifcount = response.notifcount;
            new_notifications_found();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this will help but this happened to me. The issue is with the route may be. Because error says `NotFoundException`

Change this

```
Route::get('/new-notifications-exists', 'ToolsController@count_notifz');
```

to this

```
Route::get('/new-notifications-exists', [ToolsController::class, 'count_notifz']);
```

> Import your `ToolsController` in route. `use App\Http\Controllers\ToolsController;`. (id default path)

And run

```
PHP artisan optimize
```

---

And use `return response()->json($response);` instead of `echo`